# React Native - Undefined functions onPress for TextInput

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, mobile

I'm trying to make an increment and decrements button in my app and then display the number into my textinput, but for some reason the textinput is not displaying the expected output. I not sure if my button's function has the missing piece or my textinput.

**EDIT:** I'm still not sure but my functions: " _incrementCount " and 
" _decreaseCount ", is undefined in my console.log and in my alert.

And without " string() " I'm having a warning.

Here's my code:

```
export default class Dishes extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super (props)
        this.state = {
            count: 0,
        }
    }
    _incrementCount(index) {
        this.setState({ ['count'+index]: this.state['count'+index] + 1 });
        console.log(this.count);
        alert(this.count);
    }
    _decreaseCount(index) {
        this.setState({ ['count'+index]: this.state['count'+index] - 1 });
        console.log(this.count);
        alert(this.count);
    }
    changeTextHandler(text) {
        this.setState({ ['count'+index]: text });
    };

    _renderItem = ({ item, index }) => {
     return (
        <View>
            <TouchableOpacity
                onPress = {() => this._incrementCount(index)}>
                <Text style = {styles.buttonText}> + </Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>

            <TextInput
                onChangeText={ (text) => this.changeTextHandler(text) }
                value={ this.state.count }
                keyboardType = "numeric"
                placeholder="0"
            />

            <TouchableOpacity
                onPress = {() => this._decreaseCount(index)}>
                <Text style = {styles.buttonText}> - </Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
     )
    }
```

[image]

Comment: You have a `count` in your state, but you try to set `'count' + index` in your state. Is that intentional?

Comment: ahmm yes sir I'm trying to trigger only one textinput at a time, because at first sir I'm having a problem with my text inputs. Please check it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51396776/react-native-flatlist-single-select

Comment: if it's not displaying the expected output, what is it displaying?

Comment: nothing happens when I click my buttons sir.

Comment: I just found that my functions is undefined

Answer (score 0):

You are doing many things wrong but I guess this is what you needed. You can check [this expo snack to confirm](https://snack.expo.io/@dennisja/stack-overflow-help) . You need to learn some react basics before diving into react native and [there docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/getting-started.html) are a good place to get you started

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  Text,
  View,
  StyleSheet,
  TouchableOpacity
} from 'react-native';

export default class Dishes extends Component {
  state = {
    count: 0,
  };

  _incrementCount = () => {
    this.setState(({ count }) => ({ count: count + 1 }));
  };

  _decreaseCount = () => {
    this.setState(({ count }) => ({ count: count - 1 }));
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={this._incrementCount}>
          <Text style={styles.buttonText}> + </Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>

        <Text>{this.state.count}</Text>

        <TouchableOpacity onPress={this._decreaseCount}>
          <Text style={styles.buttonText}> - </Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    flexDirection: 'row',
  },
  buttonText: {
    backgroundColor: 'red',
    margin: 5,
    padding: 5,
  },
});
```

Comment: yes sir, that is what I'm trying to get but mine in a Flatlist and I have to trigger one of my textinput at a time.