# React Native - TextInput warning and Undefined onPress

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, user-interface, react-native

Good day guys, I have two questions here.

**First** is in my textinput, I'm having a "warning" that I think it is expecting some string, so I use ".toString()" in my "value" at first and it did remove the warning but I'm seeing not any kind of output in my textinput when a button is pressed.

```
_incrementCount(index) {
    this.setState({ ['count'+index]: this.state['count'+index] + 1 });
    console.log(this.count);
    alert(this.count);
}
_decreaseCount(index) {
    this.setState({ ['count'+index]: this.state['count'+index] - 1 });
    console.log(this.count);
    alert(this.count);
}
changeTextHandler(text) {
    this.setState({ ['count'+index]: text });
};
return (
    <View>
        <TextInput
        onChangeText={ (text) => this.changeTextHandler(text) }
        value={ this.state.count }      // value
        />
    </View>
)
```

This goes to my next question..

**Second** in my buttons, I'm trying to have a increment and decrements of number and the output is should be in a textinput. But when I click/tap in my buttons the alert say's "undefined" also in my console.log.

```
    <TouchableOpacity
        onPress = {() => this._incrementCount(index)}>
        <Text style = {styles.buttonText}> + </Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
    <TextInput
        onChangeText={ (text) => this.changeTextHandler(text) }
        value={ this.state.count }
    />
    <TouchableOpacity
        onPress = {() => this._decreaseCount(index)}>
        <Text style = {styles.buttonText}> - </Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
```

**PS:** I'am using those index because of this; [React Native - Flatlist Single Select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51396776/react-native-flatlist-single-select)

Comment: You can't call `this.state.count` will be undefined as your state will be `this.state.count1` etc where `1` can be any number since you are appending an index to the state key

Answer (score 0):

For your first question you don't see anything because you set the value of the textInput to `this.state.count` but you never change `this.state.count` because on your onChange function you are setting the count + index so the result will be that you are only changing the `count + index` state and not the count state.

For your second question you are getting undefined because you are passing in your onPress function nothing. the index that you are passing is never set (according to the code that you provided).

Comment: Your first answer make it right sir, in the second.. I'm not sure. Can you be more specific?

Comment: According to the code that you provided the index that you are passing in this function `onPress = {() => this._incrementCount(**index**)} ` and in this function `onPress = {() => this._decreaseCount(**index**)}` is never set so in those two functions you are passing an undefined value.